# How to adjust the shipping costs of a specific shipping method in WooCommerce based on the user's role?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, tax

I am trying to change in shipping cost (package rate) depending on user role.

How to manage shipping costs from the total price without taxes?

There is a wholesale user type(wholesale_customer) and then there are the rest of the user roles(Let's call them "The Rest") that have the same rules for everyone.

Shipping Cost Logic:

- For wholesale customers:

  1. If the order subtotal is equal to or exceeds €70, they should get free shipping (remove the standard shipping cost).
  2. If the order subtotal is less than €70, they should be charged €10 for shipping.
- For regular customers:

  1. If the order subtotal is equal to or exceeds €30, they should get free shipping (remove the standard shipping cost).
  2. If the order subtotal is less than €30, they should be charged €5 for shipping.

You need this calculation to be made based on the subtotal without adding taxes.

Tried bellow code :

```
// This is the way I try to manage shipping costs for "The rest" user

add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_costs_for_retailers', 10, 2);
function shipping_costs_for_retailers($rates, $package) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (!in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 30) {
        $new_rate = array();
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            $new_rate[$rate_id] = $rate;
            $new_rate[$rate_id]->cost += 5;
        }
        return $new_rate;
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_shipping_html', 'message_for_retailers');
function message_for_retailers($html) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (!in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 30) {
        $html .= '<p>Shipping cost: $5.00</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

```
// This is the way I try to manage shipping costs for wholesale users

add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'shipping_ expenses_ for_wholesalers', 10, 2);
function shipping_ expenses_ for_wholesalers($rates, $package) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 70) {
        $new_rate = array();
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            $new_rate[$rate_id] = $rate;
            $new_rate[$rate_id]->cost += 10;
        }
        return $new_rate;
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_shipping_html', 'message_for_wholesalers');
function message_for_wholesalers($html) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    if (in_array('wholesale_customer', $user_roles) && $subtotal < 70) {
        $html .= '<p>Shipping cost: $10.00</p>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

What should I do to correct this?

How should I modify my function to manage the price without the tax?

You can see a screenshot of what happens to me, when a wholesale customer, in the SubTotal does not reach €70, but the shipping fee is deactivated since the total exceeds €70

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before my answer I clarify some points about your code , you are adding +10 to all rates that is added in car for example if already 20 is added in cart so now its 30 and if there is second shipping tax of 15 with it so that will be 25 and so on so 10 is adding in all tax , but you said in question that  :: "the shipping costs would be €10" , So for that we add one flat rate shipping method with zero(0) charge for all orders and we add 10 charge where we need by code , I'm giving all steps bellow

[Step : 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTyzg.png) , [step : 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NOL5.png) , [step : 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaPI8.png) , [step : 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Ord.png) , [step : 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDMwm.png) , [step : 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoMQW.png) , [step : 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pmao.png) , [step : 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkQW9.png)

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_costs_based_on_user_role', 10, 2 );
function custom_shipping_costs_based_on_user_role( $rates, $package ) {
    // Get the current user role
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_role = $current_user->roles[0];

    // Get the order subtotal without taxes
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax;
    
    if(isset($rates['flat_rate:3'])) {

        // Set the shipping costs based on the user role and subtotal
        if ( $user_role == 'wholesale_customer' ) {
            if ( $subtotal >= 70 ) {
                // Free shipping
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] ); // remove standard shipping rate
            } else {
                // Add €10 shipping cost
                $rates['flat_rate:3']->cost = 10;
            }
        } else {
            if ( $subtotal >= 30 ) {
                // Free shipping
                unset( $rates['flat_rate:3'] ); // remove standard shipping rate
            } else {
                // Add €10 shipping cost
                $rates['flat_rate:3']->cost = 5;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Hi, friend @#Yash
A configuration change for shipping costs and user roles has come up and I'm stuck. I finally asked a question to try to get someone to help me, can you review the question and tell me if I have a way to do what I'm looking for? Of course if you can help me, when the time comes I will create a nice bounty to reward your help. Thank you [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502094/how-to-adapt-the-shipping-costs-according-to-the-role-of-the-user-in-woocommerce)

Comment: my bad, I was on a break :)

Comment: Hi @Yash. Don't worry, I asked you for help because you helped me with something similar. The answer I accepted was working on a test website I have. I moved that code to the real store and did not test. After several days, I have received messages from Wholesale customers saying that their orders did not arrive, and they did it correctly, without error messages. But the orders are not coming to WooCommerce. I already left a comment to the author of the answer to see if he has any ideas. You can review the answer code if you want, I can still create a new bounty for another answer.