# WooCommerce shipping methods based on user roles and subtotal amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, shipping-method

I need to add two different shipping rates, depending on the role of the user making the purchase. I have a role that is 'wholesale_customer' and should not pay shipping costs. However, the purchase must be prevented and a message added at Checkout if the subtotal of the cart is equal to or less than €90. (remember that you must reach the amount of €90)

The other option is all other WordPress roles, who are required to pay €5 shipping if their cart subtotal is €40 or less.

I have configured shipping in WooCommerce, I have created two free shipping methods with a minimum order amount, one of €40 and another of €90.

The problem is that the user with the 'wholesale_customer' role, when he reaches the amount of €40, is also enabled for that free shipping method, which should not happen, since for this user role ('wholesale_customer ' ) shipping is free, if the purchase exceeds the minimum of €90.

I have configured the shipments in WooCommerce in the following way, creating 2 Shipping Methods:
- one has "Minimum Quantity Required" at €90

- another has "Minimum Quantity Required" at €40
- and one of shipping costs at €0.

I have tried to add the following function to add to get what I need, but all the shipping methods are always enabled, so the retail shipping method of "Minimum €40 for free shipping", is also activated for the user with the role wholesale_customer' This should not happen, as users with this role would benefit from benefits that are not theirs.

I'm showing some of the code I've used to try to do what I'm looking for, since I did a lot of testing. Only I have not had the way to add the text that I mention in the presentation for the role 'wholesale_customer'
Show images of WooCommerce setup

```
function custom_shipping_methods_visibility( $available_methods ) {
     
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_roles = $user->roles;
        
        // Check user role and cart subtotal to show/hide shipping methods
        if ( in_array( 'wholesale_customer', $user_roles ) && $subtotal <= 70 ) {
            unset( $available_methods['flat_rate:13'] );
        } elseif ( $subtotal <= 30 ) {
            unset( $available_methods['flat_rate:9'] );
        }
        
        return $available_methods;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_methods_visibility', 10, 1 );
```

////////////////////

```
// Adds a custom function to filter shipping methods based on cart role and subtotal
    function custom_shipping_methods( $available_methods ) {
        // Get cart subtotal
        $subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        
        // Gets the role of the current user
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_roles = $user->roles;
        
        //Check user role and cart subtotal to adjust shipping methods
        if ( in_array( 'wholesale_customer', $user_roles ) && $subtotal < 70 ) {
            foreach ( $available_methods as $method_id => $method ) {
                // Hide the shipping methods if the user is a wholesaler and the subtotal is less than €70
                unset( $available_methods[ $method_id ] );
            }
            
            // Show a warning message
            wc_add_notice( 'Debes alcanzar un mínimo de 70€ en tu carrito para realizar el pedido.', 'error' );
        }
        
        return $available_methods;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
```

config-1

[image]

Config-2 :

[image]

Config-3 :

[image]

Config-4 :
[image]

Comment: I was able to find this plugin with a quick search, maybe reviewiging it will help you find some techniques to re-purpose: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-based-shipping-method/

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that plugin now and it doesn't work for me. For some reason, in the settings it does not show the user role that I have in my store. I'll keep looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Updated*

First, to prevent "wholesale_customer" user placing an order if cart subtotal is less than €90, the following code will:

- display a related reminder notice on cart and checkout pages,
- display an error notice on checkout validation process, avoiding any purchase.

```php
// Conditional function: Is user a Wholesale Customer
function is_a_wholesale_customer() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return false;

    return (bool) in_array( 'wholesale_customer', wp_get_current_user()->roles );
}

// Conditional function: Is user a (normal) Customer
function is_a_normal_customer() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) return false;

    return (bool) in_array( 'customer', wp_get_current_user()->roles );
}

// Conditional function: Is "wholesale_customer" allowed to order
function is_wholesale_customer_allowed_to_order() {
    // Check "wholesale_customer" user role and required subtotal
    return is_a_wholesale_customer() && WC()->cart->subtotal < 90 ? false : true;
}

// The notice text (for "wholesale_customer")
function wholesale_customer_text_error_notice(){
    return __('Please remember that you must reach an amount of €90', 'woocommerce');
}

// Notice reminder based on required subtotal (for "wholesale_customer")
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_cart_subtotal_wholesale_customer' ); // cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'check_cart_subtotal_wholesale_customer' ); // checkout
function check_cart_subtotal_wholesale_customer() {
    if ( ! is_wholesale_customer_allowed_to_order() ) {
        wc_print_notice( wholesale_customer_text_error_notice() );
    }
}
// Checkout validation based on required subtotal (for "wholesale_customer")
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wholesale_customer_checkout_validation' );
function wholesale_customer_checkout_validation() {
    if ( ! is_wholesale_customer_allowed_to_order() ) {
        wc_add_notice( wholesale_customer_text_error_notice(), 'error' ); // Displays an error notice
    }
}
```

> For the shipping methods, your settings are correct.

The following code will show / hide shipping methods based on your user roles ("wholesale_customer" and "customer" *(adding unlogged users too)* and a minimum cart subtotal amount for free shipping.

> Update: The code works now with unlogged user (just as "customer" user role)

For the "wholesale_customer" all shipping methods will be disabled, until cart subtotal reaches €90.

When free shipping will be available, all other shipping methods will be hidden.

For each of your 2 free shipping methods, you will need to get the correct shipping rate ID. 
With a cart subtotal higher than €90, on your checkout page shipping section, inspect the displayed radio buttons for each free shipping displayed option (see the screenshot below):

[image]

Now you can set in the code below both of your 2 free shipping methods rate IDs:

```php
// showing / Hidding shipping methods
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_shipping_package_rates', 10, 2 );
function filter_shipping_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Settings
    $free_rate_ids  = array( 
        'wholesale_customer'   => 'free_shipping:2', // Here set the free shipping rate ID for wholesale user
        'customer_or_unlogged' => 'free_shipping:3', // Here set the free shipping rate ID for customer or unlogged user
    );

    $error_data['all_rates'] = array_keys($rates);
    
    // "Wholesale" user role
    if ( is_a_wholesale_customer() ) {
        $key = 'wholesale_customer';
        // show only "Wholesale" free shipping when available
        if( isset($rates[$free_rate_ids[$key]]) ) {
            return array( $free_rate_ids[$key] => $rates[$free_rate_ids[$key]] );
        } 
        // Hide all shipping methods (no free shipping available)
        else {
            return array();
        }
    } 
    // "Customer" user role or unlogged users
    else {
        $key = 'customer_or_unlogged';
        // show only "Normal" free shipping when available
        if( isset($rates[$free_rate_ids[$key]]) ) {
            return array( $free_rate_ids[$key] => $rates[$free_rate_ids[$key]] );
        } 
    } 
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Once the code is saved, **to refresh shipping methods cached data**, don't forget to empty your cart *(or disable, save and enable, save related shipping methods for the current shipping zone, in Woocommerce shipping settings)*.

Comment: After several days, I have received messages from Wholesale customers saying that their orders did not arrive, and they did it correctly, without error messages. But the orders are not coming to WooCommerce.

Comment: [WooCommerce code snippet](https://woocommerce.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/)

Comment: Could you please remove your long comments by deleting them, except the first little one, thank you.

Comment: Maybe your company should hire someone skilled, to audit everything and clean it up once forever.

Comment: You are right, thank you for your dedication and for your comments @LoicTheAztec